# Show hostname for local host with powerline

Tags: bash, hostname, powerline

I am using [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline/) with bash, fish, and tmux. The hostname shows up when logging in to remote systems with SSH. But I want to also enable the hostname segment for local users. Here is how it looks on a remote system.

[image]

Here is how it looks on as a local user. Note that I have `hostname` set on the local machine.

[image]

The `tmux` theme works fine.

[image]

I have tried editing the default theme by omitting the priority to always show the hostname segment disregarding the display width, and also edited the `"only_if_ssh": false` argument. How can I enable showing the hostname in the shell prompt as well?

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the following config files to show the hostname for a local system.

- Change `powerline/config.json` to make the key `ext:shell:theme` point to my custom theme `.json` file
- Customize the theme file to your liking. I have the following in addition to other entries.

> ```
> {
>   "segments": {
>      "left": [
>      {
>         "function": "powerline.segments.common.net.hostname",
>         "priority": 10
>      }
>   }
> }
> ```

- Edit `__main__.json` as follows.

> ```
> {
>    "segment_data": {
>      "hostname": {
>        "args": {
>          "only_if_ssh": false
>        }
>      }
>    }
>  }
> ```